# f10 does not step through loops

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am stepping through some code in VS2010. I noticed this icon in the side bar:

[image: VS Icon]

And since the apprearance of that icon, I am unable to use F10 to loop though code.

I tried changing many settings but nothing helps. I changed project properties, reset VS to default, but to no avail.

Im sure is a simple answer, but I am just not able to figure it.

UPDATE: Only happens if loop contains TRACE macro

Comment: Please don't use URLs to images (or any other resources). If the URL goes down for any reason, the question becomes pointless.

Comment: Its called a bookmark which has no influence on the debugging experience

Comment: Thanks, then my diagnosis was wrong, but problems persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove bookmarks, Check in tools for "Clear Bookmarks" or here is the shortcut to remove all bookmarks "ctrl+k then ctrl+l"

Comment: Well it was a weird problem and it seems to have solved itself! But your answer helped - so I am selecting it.